# MultiClient TCP server in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, server

I've been developing a TCP server, and I require it to allow for the access of multiple clients at the same time.

I also require it to allow them to disconnect and reconnect whenever they wish and for whenever they send a TCP message for the logic to run behind it as well.

I have my basic code set up which allows for one user to be connected at once however, it doesn't allow for multiple clients.

Server Code - (First part, without logic)

```
IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Any;
TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 5001);
myList.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a new connection");
Console.WriteLine("Last Connection From - " + client);
Console.Write("Stats - Errors: ");
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Write(" " + Errors + " ");
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine();

Console.Write(feed);
Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();

client = Convert.ToString(s.RemoteEndPoint);

Console.Write(feed);


byte[] b = new byte[100];
int k = s.Receive(b);
Console.WriteLine("\n Message Recieved");
string msg = "";
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    msg = msg + Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
}
feed = feed + " \n " + msg;
```

There is also client code which, I'm not going to put in here because I don't believe it's needed. If you have any questions or improvements/modifications about the client just ask/tell me and I'll take a look.

I've been told there is ways of doing it through another thread but I haven't got a clue to how I would approach it.

Comment: Convert your code to async or create a new thread to accept different connections. The easiest one is to use `BeginAcceptSocket`

Comment: How would i do this? Im so confused with it all.